# Get a single value from count()

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the number of ids in an array but my code outputs the count like an array instead of giving me a single value.

```
 <?php 
    foreach ($studentlistbysection as $stlist) {
        $numstudent[] = $stlist->id;
        echo count($numstudent);
    }
```

This outputs the number as `12345678910` instead of a single value like `10`
How do I count the number of ids in my array?

Comment: instead of looping over $studentlistbysection,you can simply do echo count($studentlistbysection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should count it after this loop

```
foreach ($studentlistbysection as $stlist) {
        $numstudent[] = $stlist->id;
    }
echo count($numstudent);
```